# PHP / JavaScript custom progress bar animate on changing of input value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, progress

I'm looking for an HTML5/PHP/JavaScript based progress bar that can work/animate on the changing of input values, the emotions (shown below and in link) are selectable actually they  are checkbox (See this page http://hashtaginc.us/Projects/Relax/self_assessment.php). I want when user select/deselect any emotion the progress bar animates (increase/decrease) respectively..
So any one can help me to find a way to create a custom progress bar according to my requirement.
(custom progress bar as shown in the image below)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use [Jquery UI Progressbar](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#default)

And just adjust the value depending on how many checkboxes are selected. If you would like to use a custom progressbar you can try to make css classes 0% 25% 50% 100% and just call them with jquery.